# How to update database values retrieved from a cursor in a procedure row by row?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Let's say we have a database dealing with customer loans in a business, we have a table of loans (in the simplest way 5 columns):

```
- ID           int(10) PK Auto_Increment,
- CustomerID   int(10),
- Amount       decimal(10,2),
- TotalLoan    decimal(10,2),
- Date         datetime
```

so as customers take loans daily we insert new records to the table, `TotalLoan` is a customers loan up to that time. so in case of editing an old record and correcting the `Amount` of money, the `TotalLoan` of that record and all newer ones since the edited record date must be corrected also. an approach is to make hundred of update queries in the program to update each record, which I think is not efficient and not the best way. second approach I think of is through the software's back-end code (PHP or Java) which I think is a good way unless we can perform it with MySQL procedures itself (which is most efficient), but the problem is that I can't update the value of `TotalLoan` for that row permanently in each loop, so here's a sample code I have tried so far:

```
DELIMITER //

create procedure update_loans(IN CID INT)
BEGIN 

    DECLARE amount DECIMAL DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE loan DECIMAL DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE current_total_loan DECIMAL DEFAULT 0;

    DECLARE result CURSOR FOR
        SELECT Amount, TotalLoan FROM loans WHERE CustomerID = CID ORDER BY Date ASC;

    open result;
    result_loop: LOOP
        FETCH result INTO amount, loan;
        IF finished = 1 THEN
            LEAVE result_loop;
        END IF;

        SET current_total_loan = current_total_loan + amount; 
        set loan = current_total_loan; -- changing loan variable doesn't change actual stored database value for loan in current row.

    END LOOP result_loop;
    close result;

END
```

Comment: I would expect an update statement to update the table AND where do you get the date the correction is effective from?

Comment: @P.Salmon If you commit a regular update query inside the loop, then basically it's the same as the first approach as I mentioned, which is way less efficient than the programmatic update from Java or PHP, which holds the current pointer for that row in each loop, so MySQL should not make the effort each time to find updating row internally. about the date, you're right I missed the second parameter in this example (which is not the main problem).

Comment: You would have to write 1 update and execute every cursor loop. I doubt this is 'less efficient than the programmatic update from Java or PHP' which would have to do the same.

Comment: @P.Salmon I've read some articles about programmatic update efficiency, as in [this website](https://www.progress.com/tutorials/jdbc/designing-performance)
about optimizing MySQL performance in Java under "Using updateXXX Methods", It says "programmatic updates usually result in improved performance. Because the database server is already positioned on the row for the Select statement in process, performance-expensive operations to locate the row to be changed are not needed. If the row must be located, the server usually has an internal pointer to the row available".

Comment: @JihadMehdi That doesn't apply to MySQL (at least for the InnoDB engine). The application never knows the physical address of a row like `ROWID`. The fastest way to acces a row in InnoDB is by using the PRIMARY KEY (`ID` in your case). To locate the row, MySQL have to traverse the B-tree, which results in an *O(log N)* complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand - You want to recalculate the values in the `TotalLoan` column for a specific customer. Starting from your cursor approach, I don't see any other way rather than execute an UPDATE statement for each found row. Let's see what the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cursors.html) can tell us:

> MySQL supports cursors inside stored programs. The syntax is as in
>   embedded SQL. Cursors have these properties:
>
> - Asensitive: The server may or may not make a copy of its result table
> - **Read only: Not updatable**
> - Nonscrollable: Can be traversed only in one direction and cannot skip rows

I marked the important part in bold: "**Read only: Not updatable**".

So again: You need to select a row identifier (which is `ID` in your case) and use it in the WHERE clause of the UPDATE statement in the loop. The following procedure works for me:

```
DELIMITER //

create procedure update_loans(IN CID INT)
BEGIN 

    DECLARE v_id INT;
    DECLARE v_amount DECIMAL(10,2);
    DECLARE current_total_loan DECIMAL(10,2) DEFAULT 0;

    DECLARE finished INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE result CURSOR FOR
        SELECT ID, Amount FROM loans WHERE CustomerID = CID ORDER BY Date ASC;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;

    open result;
    result_loop: LOOP
        FETCH result INTO v_id, v_amount;
        IF finished = 1 THEN
            LEAVE result_loop;
        END IF;

        SET current_total_loan = current_total_loan + v_amount; 

        UPDATE loans SET TotalLoan = current_total_loan WHERE ID = v_id;

    END LOOP result_loop;
    close result;

END //

DELIMITER ;
```

See demo on [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/m9Lm1885h4kh4zhrf6ZoNU/0)

If you use MySQL 8.0+ or MariaDB 10.2+, you can achieve the same with a single UPDATE statement using `SUM()` as window function (comulative sum) in a subquery:

```
DELIMITER //

create procedure update_loans(IN CID INT)
BEGIN 

    UPDATE loans l
    JOIN (
        SELECT ID, SUM(Amount) OVER (ORDER BY Date) as new_total
        FROM loans
        WHERE CustomerID = CID
    )x USING(ID)
    SET l.TotalLoan = x.new_total;

END //

DELIMITER ;
```

See demo on [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rHGRSLV1mjkJfou2HLr4Pc/0)

Since that is a single-statement procedure, I would just execute the UPDATE statement from the application instead of creating a procedure.

Comment: Thanks a lot, what I missed here was "Read only: Not updatable" as I got the insight of updating current row directly through programmatic update which as supposed to be much more efficient by eliminating the need of "O(log N) lookup". So I have doubt either the programmatic update approach isn't as efficient as the traditional update or MySQL for some reason didn't include this feature in procedures.

Comment: @JihadMehdi "*The server may or may not make a copy of its result table*" could be one reason. If you "work" on a copy, updates would have no effect. I know no **supported** way in MySQL to read and write row data with a single access. There is though a ["hack"](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/36wZkJUDVPcJ7HYP4J4GzW/0) using session variables. But that behavior is deprecated.

Comment: It would be much more useful If session variables can support multiple operations in case if you include minus operation for customer repayment in our example. I wonder If it can be done.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out to do it this way (while Type is record type being either taking loan(1) or repayment(0)):
`set l.TotalLoan = (@new_total := (CASE Type WHEN 1 THEN @new_total + l.Amount ELSE @new_total - l.Amount END))`